# How is the Laplace transform of the density of a specific point process computed?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, point-processes

I am trying to understand a little of [this](http://www.math.bme.hu/~rudasa/rudas_dissertation.pdf) thesis by Anna Rudas. In particular the continuous model presented in Section 2.2.2.

We are given a weight function $w: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and a Markovian pure birth process $X(t)$.  The birth process has the property that $X(0) = 0$ and the birth rates
$$ P(X(t + dt) = k+1 : X(t) = k) = w(k)dt + o(dt) $$

Rudas then defines the density $\rho$ of the point process corresponding to $X(t)$ to be 
$$ \rho(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{P((t,t+\epsilon) \text{  contains a point from $X$   } )}{\epsilon}. $$

Finally the formal Laplace transform of $\rho$ is given by 
$$\hat{\rho}(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty e^{- \lambda t} \rho(t) dt  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{w(i)}{\lambda + w(i)}.$$

**Question:**How is the far righthand side of $\hat{\rho}(\lambda)$ calculated?

Rudas states that the calculation is easy given that the intervals between successive jumps of $X(t)$ are ind. exponentially distributed variables with parameters $w(0),w(1),w(2),\dots$ respectively.

Comment: The integral in the middle is actually $E(S)$ with $S=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}e^{-\lambda T_k}$, where $(T_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ are the dates of births. Thus, $S=e^{-\lambda T_1}(1+S')$ where $S'$ is the analogue of $S$ for $(T'_k)_{k\geqslant1}=(T_{k+1}-T_1)_{k\geqslant1}$. By independence, $$\hat\rho(\lambda)=E(S)=E(e^{-\lambda T_k})(1+E(S'))=\frac{w(0)}{\lambda+w(0)}(1+E(S')).$$ In turn, $$E(S')=E(e^{-\lambda T'_1})(1+E(S''))=\frac{w(1)}{\lambda+w(1)}(1+E(S'')),$$ where the definition of $S''$ should be obvious, and one gets the formula by iterating this.

Comment: Thanks Did.  I understand your argument but I cannot understand the foundation.  Why is the integral in the middle equal to $E(S)$ where $S$ is as you have defined it?

Comment: This is merely a translation of the fact that, when $\epsilon\to0$, $$\int_0^\infty e^{- \lambda t} \epsilon^{-1}\mathbf 1_{(t,t+\epsilon)\cap X\ne\varnothing} dt\to S.$$